# Are all timespinners Weavers?

Tags: a-discovery-of-witches

The two timespinners that we saw in the series are

> Diana and her father.

Since the term itself seems to be widely known, we can probably assume that there are other timespinners, and not just those two. Coincidentally (?), both Diana and her father are Weavers. As such, both of the the timespinners that we have seen in the show are Weavers.

Is this mere coincidence, or does one imply the other?